# Jest: How to mock default export Component when same module also has named export?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, es6-modules

I have an ES6 module that exports a React Component class by default, but also exports a plain JS function as a named export. When testing other packages that use this module, I want to mock both the default exported component and named exported function to keep my unit tests pure.

The module looks something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello</div>
  }
}

export function myUtilityFunction() { return 'foo' };
```

I would like to use the following syntax to mock the exports:

```
import React from 'react';
import MyComponent, { myUtilityFunction } from './module';

jest.mock('./module');
MyComponent.mockImplementation(() => 'MockComponent');
myUtilityFunction.mockImplementation(() => 'foo');
```

When I try to use this syntax, however, MyComponent does not appear to be mocked when used within other components. When I try to mock MyComponent like this and render it on its own, it renders out to null.

This behavior is very strange, because if I use the exact same syntax, but both imports are JavaScript functions, the mocking works as expected. See the StackOverflow issue I opened here that confirms that the syntax works when the imports are both functions.

Here is a GitHub repo demoing the problem, as well as several solutions I've tried: https://github.com/zpalexander/jest-enzyme-problem

You can build the repo and run the tests with yarn install && yarn test

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is that the ShallowWrapper class's getElement method needs to be passed a class that contains a render method. To do that, your MyComponent.mockImplementation needs to more fully mock a class constructor.

For details on how to mock a class constructor, see the Jest documentation starting at "mockImplementation can also be used to mock class constructors:" https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockimplementationfn

Using the Jest documentation as a model, we can mock the MyComponent class constructor *and* make it shallow renderable by enzyme like this:

```
MyComponent.mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    render: () => <div>MockComponent</div>
  };
});
```

Now when getElement goes looking for a render method it will find it.

Here's a gist that implements this change on the  App.mockImplementation.test.js file from your repo: https://gist.github.com/timothyjellison/a9c9c2fdfb0b30aab5698dd92e901b24

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thanks for the response. I wish there was a way to do this with less boilerplate, but according to the Jest maintainers everything is working as expected: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5579#event-1477087994

Answer (score 15):

The other solution didn't work for me. This is how I did:

```
  jest.mock('./module', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    myUtilityFunction: 'myUtilityFunction',
    default: 'MyComponent'
  }));
```

Another way to do it:

```
jest.unmock('../src/dependency');

const myModule = require('../src/dependency');
myModule.utilityFunction = 'your mock'
```

Comment: This works for the most part, although to get the test to pass in my example repo you need to change `myUtilityFunction: 'myUtilityFunction` to `myUtilityFunction: () => 'myUtilityFunction'`

Comment: The `__esModule: true` part is critical! Without it, Jest thinks its an object, not a module, and raises an error.